# ModelForm set instance file input change text

Tags: django

I have the following code:

```
advertisement = Advertisement.objects.get(id=advertisementid)
form = AdvertisementForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,
                                  instance=advertisement)
```

I'd like to change the text **Currently**, **Change** which is initially set by Django in my HTML-View where a image or file can be chosen. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Advertiesment form, its probably using a ClearableInputWidget.

You can create a new ClearableInputWidget modifying initial_text

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
....

class MyClearableInputWidget(ClearableInputWidget):
    initial_text = _('Latest File')
```

And in your form, have that field use this custom widget.